# Measures on the composition of the unemployed by educational attainment in the US

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, data-request, unemployment, education-economics

I am trying to find statistics on the profile of unemployed individuals in the U.S. categorized by educational attainment. I have [found](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/empsit.t04.htm) statistics on the unemployment rate for each education group (e.g. U rate for HS graduates is 8%, but 3 for college graduates), but that is not what I am looking for.

I am essentially interested in knowing of the X number unemployed people in the U.S., what is the proportion or percentage have a HS degree or less?